# Diophantine equation problem

Tags: diophantine-equations

We sold respectively $m$ and $n$ units of items A and B. Assume $m ≥ 1$, and the price of each unit of A is $\$3$ more than the price of each unit of B. Assume a total of $12$ units of both items was sold, and the price of the total was $1320$. Use a Diophantine equation to determine the price and the number of each the items
A and B sold.

Comment: Can you show us some of your effort? What have you tried?

Comment: @Dovah-king I have no clue as to how to begin this one. Your help would be much appreciated.